replace() and if/else in list comprehension to create a new list
The quiz problem is supposed to replace the file name .hpp with .h while keeping the rest using list comprehension. Some posts suggest that I must put in [do_something else if condition for x in range] order, but it didn't work either. The error message kept pointing to the else.
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
new_filenames = [name.replace("hpp", "h") for name in filenames if name.endswith("hpp") else name for name in filenames]
print(new_filenames)

It should print:
["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]

But my output is only this, when I dropped the else and after:
"stdio.h", "sample.h", "math.h"

This message when the above was run:
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 6:
new_filenames = [name.replace("hpp", "h") for name in filenames if name.endswith("hpp") else name for name in filenames]
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
)


The name.replace("hpp", "h") should be run if the name ends with hpp. If it does not, you should return the name.
This part of the list comprehension for name in filenames should be there only once at the end of the notation.
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
new_filenames = [name.replace("hpp", "h") if name.endswith("hpp") else name for name in filenames]
print(new_filenames)

Output
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']


This will still break “unhppy.hpp”. See removesuffix; I recommend including the dot.

@Ry- That is correct, but I think the question is more about the syntax. Otherwise you could also use a regex with re.sub to narrow down the replacement even more like \.hpp\b

I tried running the code with a new script, and it should work. In your case it worked, but I'm not sure...
The problem should be that you can't use if-else at the end of list comprehension, but you can do it in the value:
[value for iterating_value in iterator if condition]
My script is:
new_filenames = [name.replace("hpp", "h") if name.endswith('hpp') else name for name in filenames]

Here I'm using name.replace("hpp", "h") if name.endswith('hpp') else name as the value, it's like using ? and : in JavaScript.
The output from my script using print() is:
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']


You can use string slicing for this. There's no need for replace, endswith or regex as suggested in some comments.
Check the last three chars match hpp
name[-3:] == "hpp"

If so, slice off the pp
name[:-2]

Full example:
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
new_filenames = [name[:-2] if name[-3:] == "hpp" else name for name in filenames]
print(new_filenames)

The error you were getting was caused by using the incorrect order for conditional list comprehensions.
You used for in if else for in:
[x for x in the_list if x == some_condition else x for x in the_list]

It needs to be this if else for in:
[x if x == some_condition else x for x in the_list]

No doubt this is way too late for your quiz. It just popped up in my feed…
